# MIPS Assembly, lui 0x1001

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have an assignment in which I have to explain some things about the following MIPS Assembly code:

```
.data
x: .word 4711
y: .word 10
z: .word 0x0A91
e: .word 0

.text
.globl main
main:
lw $2, x
lw $3, y
lw $4, z
add $2, $2, $3
sub $3, $2, $4
sw $3, e
li $2, 10
syscall
```

The first instruction `lw $2, x` is separated into two instructions when assembled. The instructions are `lui $1, 0x00001001` followed by `lw $2, 0x00000000($1)`. I understand that lui moves the hex value 1001 into the upper part of the register and the value stored in $1 at this point is 0x10010000, but I do not understand where the 1001 comes from and what the second instruction means at all. I would really appreacitate any help on the subject.I am using MARS to assemble and run this program.

Comment: `0x10010000` happens to be the address of `x`.

Comment: Oh, ok then. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIPS instructions are 32 bits longs, and so are the addresses uses by a program.
This implies that the [`lw`](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) instruction is unable to specify a full 32-bit address as an immediate.
Simply put, the instruction `lw $t, var` is not valid (expect for very few cases).

In fact, its encoding is

```
lw $t, offset($s)
1000 11ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

Where the *i* bits show that only 16 bits are used to specify an address (and that a base register must always be specified, eventually the `$zero` register can be used).

So the assembler does this trick: whenever you use a `lw $t, var` it assembles that instruction into *two* instructions, one that load the upper 16 bits of the address into `$at` and a `lw` that use `$at` as a base register with the lower 16 bits of the address as the offset.

```
lui $at, ADDR_H            #ADDR_H is ADDR >> 16
lw $t, ADDR_L($at)         #ADDR_L is ADDR & 0xffff
```

Note that since the `lw` reads from `$at` + *ADDR_L* the final address used is *ADDR_H* << 16 + *ADDR_L* = *ADDR*. As expected.

<sup><sub>There is subtlety here, pointed out by [Mike Spivey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208707/mips-assembly-lui-0x1001/41210068?noredirect=1#comment85015145_41210068) (Many thanks to him), see below</sub></sup>

This kind of instructions, that doesn't map directly into the ISA, are called *pseudo-instruction*.
The `$at` register is reserved for the assembler exactly for implementing them.

---

In MARS you can disable the pseudo instructions by unchecking *Settings > Permits extended (pseudo) instructions and format*.
While programming without pseudo-instructions will grow annoying pretty quickly, it is worth doing at least once, to fully understand the MIPS architecture.

---

[Mike Spivey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208707/mips-assembly-lui-0x1001/41210068?noredirect=1#comment85015145_41210068) correctly noted that the 16-bit offset immediate is *sign-extended* before being added to the base register.
This calls for a correction of the value I called `ADDR_H` in case `ADDR_L` turns out to be negative when interpreted as a 16-bit two's complement number.
If this turns out to be true, `ADDR_H` must be incremented.
The general formula for `ADDR_H` can be corrected to `ADDR_H = ADDR >> 16 + ADDR[15]` where `ADDR[15]` denotes the value of bit 15 of `ADDR` (which is the sign bit of `ADDR_L`.

Comment: One small error: the offset in an lw instruction is signed, so it's not correct to compute ADDR_H with a shift alone.  If ADDR_L turns out negative, then ADDR_H needs to be increased by 1 to compensate.  The assembler looks after this, of course.

Comment: @MikeSpivey Thank you very much! That's a very good point! I believe it suffices to add bit15 of the original address to ADDR_H to fix it. I'm editing the answer.

Comment: When writing a MIPS assembler, I put
short ADDR_L = (short) ADDR;
short ADDR_H = (ADDR - ADDR_L) >>16;
assert(ADDR == ADDR_H << 16 + ADDR_L);
which amounts to the same thing.