# Confusion about load word (lw) vs load address(la) and offsets in mips assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

So I'm pretty new to assembly and I got so many questions. For example, if in the data segment I type this

```
.data

n:.word 4
```

And in the text segment

```
.text
lw $t0, n
```

Does $t0 now store the value 4 or the address of n?
Because I know that if n were an array and if I type lw $t0 4(n) $t0 stores the first VALUE of n(the content). And if I type lw $t0 n then $t0 stores the address.

Also I am wondering if I were to set an offset of 4 to register $0 like this:

```
lw $t0 4($0)
```

would $t0 just hold 0?

Answer (score 13):

**`lw` load a word from memory.**
`lw $t0, n` reads from the address of the symbol `n`.
`lw $t0, 4($t1)` reads from the address generated as `$t1 + 4`.
`lw $t0, 0x10000` reads from the address `0x10000`.

Apart from the second, all are pseudo-instructions.

**`la` load an address.**
`la $t0, n` puts the address of the symbol `n` in `$t0`.
`la $t0, 4($t1)` put the address generated as `$t1 + 4` in `$0`.

These are all pseudo-instructions.

**`li` load an immediate.**
`li $t0, 10000` puts the immediate 10000 in `$t0`.

This is a pseudo instruction.

---

[The central point is that MIPS has 16-bit immediates (constants) for I-type instructions, so the real form of `li` and `lw` don't permit to move a value greater than 0x10000 or access and address above 0x10000.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41210068/5801661)
The assembler gets around it by generating two or more instructions.
`la` isn't needed in theory, `li` could be used to load the address of a symbol since the said address is an immediate in this context but a specific mnemonic was introduced instead.

Comment: It's arguable whether you call `lw $t0, 10000` as pseudo-instruction or not.  Leaving out the register component of the addressing mode is equivalent to using `$zero`, and the constant is small enough that `lw $t0, 10000($zero)` can be encoded.  It definitely assembles to one instruction, with any good assembler.  And BTW, I'd say that `li` is *always* a pseudo-instruction because there's no opcode with that mnemonic.  But if the high or low 16 bits are all zero, it can get the job done in only one machine instruction.  (You only mentioned the high16 being zero case)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks Peter, I was somehow under the impression that `li` was a real instruction. The `lw` case was missing a `0x` prefix.

Comment: `li` is a pseudo for `lui` (load upper immediate: `imm16 << 16`) and/or `ori`.  (Some assemblers choose `addiu` for the low half).  Operands for addiu / addi are sign-extended, but http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html doesn't say that for ORI.  If that's accurate, then in one instruction you can generate `[0..0xffff]` (`ori`) or `[-32768 .. 32767]` (`addiu`), or anything with the low 16 cleared (`lui`).

Comment: Yeah, that's neat.  Just checked https://rivoire.cs.sonoma.edu/cs351/wemips/, and `addiu $s1, $zero, -32760` is encodeable, but it complains for `ori`.  And `ori   $s2, $zero, 65534` is encodeable.  The values in registers are sign and zero extended.  So whoever wrote that simulator agrees with my reading of that MIPS instruction-set summery at least :P

Comment: Holy crap, I checked this with MARS, and `addiu` is a pseudo-instruction: `addiu $t0, $zero, 60000` assembles to `lui $1, 0x0` / `ori $1, $1, 0xea60` / `addu $8, $0, $1`!  Total confirmation that addiu sign-extends, and ori zero-extends its immediate, and a brain-dead assembler that doesn't optimize out the LUI.

Comment: IDK if other MIPS assemblers are like that, or if they would reject out-of-range immediates instead of silently making inefficient code!  Oh probably not, MARS has a menu setting for "Permit extended (pseudo) instructions and formats" which is enabled by default.

Comment: @PeterCordes Nice findings! I like MARS but I would never expect it to optimize code :)

Comment: MARS's assembler does a good job for regular pseudo-instructions, only being dumb / simple for its "extended" cases.  e.g. `li -3000` => a single `addiu`;  `li 60000` => a single `ori`!  Based on the tooltip when you type an `li` mnemonic, it has 3 patterns: small negative, small non-negative, and 32-bit.  It doesn't notice the case where the low 16 bits are all zero, so `lui` alone would have done the job, emitting a useless `ori` with zero.  That's pretty reasonable for MARS, like you say wouldn't expect it to be optimal, but not confusingly using useless instructions is a good thing.