# MIPS32: ld pseudo instruction translation

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I am trying to understand how the pseudo instruction in MIPS32 "ld" works. I use the MARS Simulator to test the code.
When MARS assembles the following Code

```
    .data
LEN:
    .word 12
.text
ld $6, LEN
```

it says in basic code

```
lui $1, 0x00001001
lw $6, 0x00000000($1)
lui $1, 0x00001001
lw $7, 0x00000004($1)
```

The lw instructions seem to do everything needed: It loads 32 bits at the specific address 0x00000000 into Register $6 and the following 32 Bit into the following Register.

The lui instruction seem useless to me. It even does the same thing twice, why?
It is used as Offset for the lw instruction, but it must have twice the same value, otherwise we dont get the 64 bit at the memory address, but two "random" 32 bits?

Can anyone help me where my mistake in thinking is? It is probably completely different than I think...

Comment: How does `$7` come into it?  Did you actually assemble two `ld` instructions?

Comment: @PeterCordes `ld` in MIPS is "load double word" (64b), it loads the specified register + next one, so `$6` means `$6+$7` in `ld`.  (the x86 32b "double word" keeps confusing me :) )

Comment: @Ped7g: Thanks, I didn't know MARS supported much more than the classic MIPS I ISA, so I didn't know `ld` existed.  (Loading beyond the one `.word` also made me think the OP wasn't showing everything.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It was just a mistake. I wrote my first bit of MIPS code yesterday, so I am still a total beginner^^

Comment: Yup, understood.  It's totally normal that your code will have mistakes and even be confusing to people.  Didn't help that I didn't know what `ld` was supposed to do. :P  I mostly do x86.

Answer (score 1):

The `LEN` is inside `.data` segment at offset +0, which is address `0x0000100100000000` (start of `.data` segment).

So the `lw` instructions are fetching the data from address `0x0000100100000000+0` and `0x0000100100000000+4`, that's calculated from `$1 + 0` and `$1 + 4`.

The `lui` sets that value into `$1`.

Twice, because MARS assembler is sort of "dumb", producing native MIPS instructions in fixed way, not optimizing special cases where the value is already in `$1` register. Some of the pseudo instructions can be even implemented in more effective way, if you would check all of them, it's not like MARS is producing most optimal variant.

You can theoretically remove the second `lui` in this particular case without affecting the result, but removing the first `lui` would make the `lw` to access completely different memory area (as the `$1` register would contain different value).

---

EDIT: btw, you did reserve only single `.word` for LEN, so the second `lw` is fetching value beyond that word, usually in more complex source that would be bug/oversight.

And if you would reserve `LEN` after some other `.data` memory already used, the `lui` would be followed by `ori` to put into `$1` complete address including lower 16 bits. It's one of rare MARS optimizations, to remove the `ori` of "load address" when the low 16 bits are all zeroes.

I guess the `ld` would then look like `lui, ori, lw, lui, ori, lw`, i.e. there would be even more redundancy.

Comment: I'm not sure MARS is that dumb; `lw $7, 0x00000004($1)` shows that MARS knows how to put the low half of the address into the immediate displacement in `lw`.  MARS is terrible with "extended" pseudo-instructions, but for the basic pseudo-instructions that all normal MIPS assemblers support [it did a decent job last I looked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550512/confusion-about-load-word-lw-vs-load-addressla-and-offsets-in-mips-assembly#comment86173803_49552715).

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm 100% sure there's some room for improvements even in basic pseudo-instructions, but can't recall particular example, was something about negation or bit test, which was possible to rewrite with one less native instruction. It's decent, but not optimal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I understand it now. So register $1 contains the address of the 64 bit value that will be loaded into Register $6 and $7, doesnt it?

Comment: @user84037 yes. The `$1` has alias `$at` = "assembler temporary", it's a register used often when the MARS assembler is implementing the pseudo instructions with native instructions, and you as programmer are supposed to not use `$at` for your own purposes, to avoid surprise of it being modified unexpectedly (of course if you understand fully what the assembler is doing, and when it does use `$at`, you can freely use it in your own code too, just remembering when the assembler will use it too). So the `ld` is like `$at = address of data`, then 2x `lw` to load data, with +0 and +4 displacement.