# What is the difference between lw and la in this program of MIPS assembly?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
#enter a string and show it 

.data 
prompt: .asciiz "enter a string >"
input_str: .space 81
input_sz: .word 80

.text

main:

# display the prompt
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt
syscall

# type a string, and save the input
li $v0, 8 # store the string in $v0
la $a0, input_str
lw $a1, input_sz 
syscall

# display the inputted string
li $v0, 4
la $a0, input_str
syscall

#terminate the program
li $v0, 10  
syscall
```

The above program apparently works fine.
Changing `lw` to `la` makes no difference.
I.e. the program still works.

So, What is the difference between `lw` and `la` in this program of MIPS assembly?

Comment: What does the instruction reference say? Questions are better received when showing research (and providing hypothesis).

Comment: Also, please search .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550512/confusion-about-load-word-lw-vs-load-addressla-and-offsets-in-mips-assembly (and use such to ask a more refined question, eliding the “bait”)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Changing lw to la makes no difference.
>   I.e. the program still works.

... but this does not mean that the instructions have the same effect.

If you replace `100` by `10000` in the following C instruction: `fgets(fl,buffer,100)`, the program will also still work with a high probability!

> So, What is the difference between `lw` and `la` in this program of MIPS assembly?

**lw**

`lw` loads the value which is stored at a certain address. So `lw $a1, input_sz` will load the value 80 into the register `a1` because the value 80 is stored at the address that is specified by the label `input_sz`.

**la**

`la` loads the address of the label itself into the register. Example: If the label `input_sz` is located at address 100, the value 100 will be loaded into the `a1` register by the instruction `la $a1, input_sz`.

It does not matter what is stored at this address. The CPU won't read it.